# How can I request a field from a date to a date with SOAP request XML?

Tags: api, soap

I try to extract all datas that matching with a ditetimerange condition using soap api xml to Archer plateform.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://archer-tech.com/webservices/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:ExecuteSearch><web:sessionToken>6227E03F9FDCD7449FC961C7B6940C2E</web:sessionToken>
         <web:searchOptions><![CDATA[<SearchReport>
    <PageSize>9999999</PageSize>
    <DisplayFields>
        <DisplayField name="Incident_ID">15483</DisplayField>
        <DisplayField name="Alert Type">14760</DisplayField>
        <DisplayField name="Summary">14025</DisplayField>
        <DisplayField name="Alert_Source">15529</DisplayField>
        <DisplayField name="Creation Date">15518</DisplayField>
        <DisplayField name="Last Updated">15481</DisplayField>
        <DisplayField name="Application">15494</DisplayField>
        <DisplayField name="Title">15488</DisplayField>
        <DisplayField name="Urgency">15485</DisplayField>

    </DisplayFields>
    <Criteria>
        <Filter>
            <Conditions>
                <DateTimeRangeFilterCondition>
                    <Field name="Last Updated">15481</Field>
                    <BeginDate>05/16/2019</BeginDate>
                    <BeginTime>06:00 am</BeginTime>
                    <EndDate>05/16/2019</EndDate>
                    <EndTime>08:45 am</EndTime>
                    <TimeZoneId>Romance Standard Time</TimeZoneId>
                    <IsTimeIncluded>TRUE</IsTimeIncluded>
                </DateTimeRangeFilterCondition>
            </Conditions>
        </Filter>
        <ModuleCriteria>
            <Module name="Incidents">445</Module>
        </ModuleCriteria>
    </Criteria>
</SearchReport>]]></web:searchOptions>
         <web:pageNumber>1</web:pageNumber>
      </web:ExecuteSearch>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The problem is that the begin date condition only takes into account the creation date field and not Last updated. 
As a result, I don't have the right results.
If anyone has an idea I'm a taker:)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
I finaly find a way to solve my issue.

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:web="http://archer-tech.com/webservices/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <web:ExecuteSearch> 
   <web:sessionToken>6227E03F9FDCD7449FC961C7B6940C2E</web:sessionToken>
             <web:searchOptions><![CDATA[<SearchReport>
        <PageSize>9999999</PageSize>
        <DisplayFields>
            <DisplayField name="Incident_ID">15483</DisplayField>
            <DisplayField name="Alert Type">14760</DisplayField>
            <DisplayField name="Summary">14025</DisplayField>
            <DisplayField name="Alert_Source">15529</DisplayField>
            <DisplayField name="Creation Date">15518</DisplayField>
            <DisplayField name="Last Updated">15481</DisplayField>
            <DisplayField name="Application">15494</DisplayField>
            <DisplayField name="Title">15488</DisplayField>
            <DisplayField name="Urgency">15485</DisplayField>
    </DisplayFields>
        <Criteria>
            <Filter>
                <Conditions>
            <DateRangeFilterCondition>
    <Operator>Between</Operator>
    <Field>15481</Field>
    <BeginValue>2019-05-16T06:00:00</BeginValue>
    <EndValue>2019-05-16T09:00:00</EndValue>
    <TimeZoneId>Romance Standard Time</TimeZoneId>
    <IsTimeIncluded>TRUE</IsTimeIncluded>
    </DateRangeFilterCondition>
            </Conditions>
        </Filter>
        <ModuleCriteria>
            <Module name="Incidents">445</Module>
        </ModuleCriteria>
    </Criteria>
    </SearchReport>]]></web:searchOptions>
         <web:pageNumber>1</web:pageNumber>
      </web:ExecuteSearch>
   </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```